# Working with data and time intervals

Tags: java, design, architecture, time, reporting

I have an application that measures that continuously. (About every second - it depends on the device)
For example sake, let's say that data is `CPUTemp` (as used as an example in an answer to a related question: [Clean Architecure: Creating an entity from a set of other entities](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/347704/clean-architecure-creating-an-entity-from-a-set-of-other-entities/347707#347707))

Each measurement's data is written to the `CPU_TEMP_SAMPLE` table.

At the end of each day I compress the data calculating the min, max and average for that day and writing the data to a `CPU_TEMP_DAY` table.

I have a `CpuTempRepository` that get's the data either by calculating it from the `CPU_TEMP_SAMPLE` table (if it is for the current day) or just reading it from the `CPU_TEMP_DAY` table if it is for a previous day.

I want to be able to get the min and max reading for specific intervals from the `CPU_TEMP_SAMPLE`. (So instead of just returning the max temperature sample for that day I want to get the max temperature recorded over 30 seconds - so I am actually compressing 30 seconds worth of measurements into one sample)

How would I do this? 
One way is to write each interval's min, max and average data to a new table `CPU_TEMP_INTERVAL` every 30 seconds and then get the max & min from there, but I am not sure if this is the right way - what if I need to calculate for different intervals?

Comment: In general I struggle to work with data across time intervals. (Generating reports etc..) I am never sure on how to store and access the data. If somebody could point me in the direction of good resources to learn this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you sacrifice detailed data for a daily record updated with min, max and running average?

Answer (score 1):

Executing multiple queries in short period of time and then repeat the process would stress your database and would consume a lot more of resources.

You can send the data to an queue tag it with timestamp

`timestamp : measurement`

then have a worker that process the queue an executes queries to the database.

You can also temporarily work with in memory cache and have it create a Set every hour that holds measurements taken every 30 seconds , send the serialized data to be stored into database.

There are other approaches thought but consider that you don't have to store to database every in small intervals although I doubt that it will be a problem nowdays with database able to perform well under stress.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what type of system you're working on. If your temperature is in the 0-255° range, it can be stored as a single byte per sample. So storing an entire days worth of temperature samples at 1 sample per second = 1 byte * 60 samples/minute * 60 minutes/hour * 24 hours / day = 86,400 bytes/day, or about 86k. This is peanuts on most modern systems, including cell phones. On smaller embedded systems, it might be a bigger deal. But if you can spare ~90k, just store a table locally for the temperatures and do the calculations on-the-fly when requested.